# Coding Data from a Database into a table in PHP

Tags: php, css, sql, database, html-table

I am a beginner in Web Design and have only been studying it for about two months. I have been given the assignment to code the data from the database into a table in PHP, this is the code I have for now. Could anyone please fix the code or explain this to me>

The code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
<head>
 <title>Title of the document</title>
 <meta name="description" content="sampleMySqlQueries.php" />
 <meta name="keywords" content="type, keywords, here" />
 <meta name="author" content="Your Name" />
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" /> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css" />
</head>

<body>
<?php
//--- declare variables
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "myhighschool";

//--- read form arguments


//--- MAIN CODE  -------------------------------------------------------------

//ReadRecords1();
//InsertRecords2();
ReadAllData();
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// FONCTIONS
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

//--- This function gets data from a MySQL database
function ReadAllData(){
    global $servername, $username, $password, $dbname;  

    // Connect to the database
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    // Prepare the SQl statement and send it to the database
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM (tStudents INNER JOIN tEnrollments 
    ON tStudents.stuID = tEnrollments.enrStudentID 
    INNER JOIN tClasses ON tEnrollments.enrClassID = tClasses.claID 
    ORDER BY claSubject, claID, stuLastName, stuFirstName";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    // Loop through the resulting set of records (recordset)
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "Class ID: " . $row["claID"]. " - Description: " . $row["claSubject"]. " - Room: " . $row["claRoomID"]. "<br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
}

//--- This function inserts records in a MySQL database
function InsertRecords(){
    global $servername, $username, $password, $dbname;  

    // Connect to the database
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    // Prepare the SQl statement and send it to the database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tClasses (claID, claSubject, claRoomID) 
        VALUES ('201409', 'Humanities', '304')";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }

}
$i=0;
$c="";
    while(#row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if ($row["claSubject"} !=$c) {
        echo "<tr>\n<td style=\"width:200px; background-color:#00CCFF;\">" .$row["ClaID"] ."</td>";
        echo "<td style=\"background-color:#00CCFF;\">" .$row["claSubject"] ."</td>\n";
        echo "<td style=\"width:200px; background-color:#00CCFF;\">&n";
        }

        $i++;
        $color="#CCFFFF";

        if($i/2 == intval($i/2)){

//--- This function updates records in a MySQL database
function UpdateRecords(){


}

//--- This function deletes data from a MySQL database
function DeleteRecords(){


}


?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you getting any error ?  can you `elaborate Could anyone please fix the code or explain`

Comment: `$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));` and you will see the error(s). You have a few.

Comment: Results from using ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ were? Or, are these comments not being read at all? You also have a scope issue.

Comment: Sorry, I was busy trying to fix the problem on my own. But it did not work out, do you have any more tips?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: You see this `while(#row` that's wrong.